# Unmarshalling soap response in Android

Tags: android, soap, jaxb, saxparser, unmarshalling

I have two applications , client application(mobile app) having android & server application having Java programming language.
I have used jaxb to marshal my custom list.

```
          Keyword objKeyword=new Keyword();
          objKeyword.setKeywordList(keywordList); //keywordList=new ArrayList<Keyword>();

          JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Keyword.class);
          Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();
          mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

          sw = new StringWriter();

          mar.marshal(objKeyword, sw);
```

I am getting response in my android application by writing following line of codes,

```
     // Create request by specifying Namespace and Operation Name
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_NAMESPACE, "getList");

       //   Creating envelope
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

      //    Setting output SOAP object
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       //   Creating HTTP call object
       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

        //  Invoking web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(WSDL_NAMESPACE + "getList", envelope);

        //  Getting the response
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

In my response I am getting my custom list in following format,

```
<My_list>
  <keyList>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Key1</name>
   </keyList>

  <keyList>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Key2</name>
   </keyList>
</My_list>
```

Now ,I want to unmarshal soap response in my android client application.
I have read that JAXB cannot be used with android, instead XML parsing using SAX parser can be done.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to unmarshall it,
I can get the entire list in my response by using following line of code,

```
//  Getting the response
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Then I can get the list count using ,

```
int iResponseCount=response.getPropertyCount();
```

And subsequently for loop with

```
    List<Keys> lstKeys=new ArrayList<Keys>();
    for (int i = 0; i < iResponseCount; i++) {
            SoapObject responseKey =(SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);

            Keys objKeys =new Keys();
            objKeys.setId(responseKey.getProperty(0).toString());
            objKeys.setName(responseKey.getProperty(1).toString());

            lstKeys.add(objKeys);
    }
```

PS: I have also changed the return type of my server's application function (written in java) from String to,

```
List<Keys>
```